# Is it possible to pass optional parameter testIncludes or testExcludes to maven compile plugin through the command line?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin

1. Is it possible to pass optional parameter testIncludes or testExcludes to maven compile plugin through the command line?

   **I need to pass some .java as optional parameters.**

Something like

```
mvn clean verify test-compile -DtestIncludes=**/course/MyTest.java,**/course/CompileMeWithMyTest.java,etc
```

On the page http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html testIncludes and testExcludes don't have mentioned User Property

testIncludes:

A list of inclusion filters for the compiler. 

Type: java.util.Set 

Since: 2.0 

Required: No

testExcludes:

A list of exlusion filters for the compiler.

Type: java.util.Set

Since: 2.0

Required: No

2. If there is no any possible variants for the question 1.
   Is it possible somehow to set include/exclude java classes/folders in the next profile using command line.

   ```
    <profile>
       <id>only-necessary-classes</id>
       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>2.3</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <source>${java-version}</source>
                       <target>${java-version}</target>
                   </configuration>
                   <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <id>default-testCompile</id>
                           <phase>test-compile</phase>
                           <configuration>
                               <testIncludes>
                                   <include>**/tests/projectname/course/CheckQuizWithNewAccount.java</include>
                                   <include>**/tests/projectname/course/V8GenericTests.java</include>
                               </testIncludes>
                           </configuration>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>testCompile</goal>
                           </goals>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </build>
   </profile>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Create you own property and use it in testIncludes\testExcludes blocks.

mvn clean verify -Dinclude=**/course/MyTest.java

```
<properties>
    <include>some test</include>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <testIncludes>
                            <include>${include}</include>
                        </testIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what if I need to pass 2 or move test to include section?